# Number Duplicate values in view

Tags: mysql

Good Day

I am trying to number duplicate values. It's easy to use in a normal query but i need it in a view.

```
+------+--------+--------+
| Code | Alpha  | ISO    |
+------+--------+--------+
| B1123|   A    | AU     |
| B2343|   C    | AU     |
| C6678|   A    | AU     |
| D8980|   B    | AU     |
| D7789|   A    | AU     |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Trying to number Alpha Column Result =

```
+------+--------+--------+-------+
| Code | Alpha  | ISO    |  Num  |
+------+--------+--------+-------+
| B1123|   A    | AU     |   1   |
| B2343|   C    | AU     |   1   |
| C6678|   A    | AU     |   2   |
| D8980|   B    | AU     |   1   |
| D7789|   A    | AU     |   3   |
+------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Did use:

```
CREATE VIEW `Nr` AS 
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number,code,Alpha,iso
FROM MyDatabase
ORDER BY Alpha;
```

but that cannot create a view cannot use SET.

I also tried the count() function but it also does not work.

What else can i do to get a numbered column in a view.

Thanks

Ruan

Comment: In MySQL, views are of limited use, so I wonder why you need this.

Comment: So how will I be able to create the line number in a table?

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which makes the problem difficult - and somewhat spurious.

Comment: The Code is a PRIMARY KEY but cannot count the Code because it's unique there are no duplicates.

Comment: If the Code was PRIMARY, then the 5th row would 'naturally'* appear before the 4th row. (* I use this term very loosely because, of course, there is no 'natural' order in an RDBMS)

Comment: You are correct, just used that example to show how the numbers must be able to display randomly. Sorry about that.

Comment: So the order of results is random? Why then would you enumerate them? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an ID column (or any unique column), you can use that in a correlated subquery to find the sequence number using aggregate function count:

```
select code,
    alpha,
    iso,
    (
        select count(*)
        from mydatabase t2
        where t1.alpha = t2.alpha
        and t2.id <= t1.id
    ) as num
from mydatabase t1;
```

Comment: I get this error: ERROR 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Comment: @Ruan totally forgot. You can't use user variables in view. Do you have an id column in the table?

Comment: I can add one but cannot make it a PRIMARY KEY because the API that I use on my Phone app can not have multiple PRIMARY KEYS. That is fine because I lookup the Code. If I add a ID (INT) column. Will there be a way to get the numbering?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(CodeX CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,CodeY INT NOT NULL
,Alpha  CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,ISO    CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(CodeX,CodeY)
,INDEX(CodeX,Alpha)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('B',1123,'A','AU'),
('B',2343,'C','AU'),
('C',6678,'A','AU'),
('D',8980,'B','AU'),
('D',7789,'A','AU');

CREATE TABLE my_new_table AS
SELECT Code,Alpha,ISO, @i:=@i+1 id FROM my_table, (SELECT @i:=0) vars;

SELECT * FROM my_new_table;
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| Code  | Alpha | ISO | id   |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| B1123 | A     | AU  |    1 |
| B2343 | C     | AU  |    2 |
| C6678 | A     | AU  |    3 |
| D8980 | B     | AU  |    4 |
| D7789 | A     | AU  |    5 |
+-------+-------+-----+------+


SELECT a.Code
     , a.Alpha
     , a.ISO
     , a.i 
  FROM  
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = alpha THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev := alpha
         FROM my_new_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY alpha
            , id
     ) a
 ORDER
    BY id;
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| Code  | Alpha | ISO | i    |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
| B1123 | A     | AU  |    1 |
| B2343 | C     | AU  |    1 |
| C6678 | A     | AU  |    2 |
| D8980 | B     | AU  |    1 |
| D7789 | A     | AU  |    3 |
+-------+-------+-----+------+
```